# Export mySQL into CSV using OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, csv

I've tried using PHP scripts found online with no success, so i reverted to using the mySQL Syntax OUTFILE, here's the current code i'm trying to use although it's throwing a few errors

```
SELECT Name, ID INTO OUTFILE 'data.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM data
```

It's throwing an error as shown below

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this error is thrown by PHP.  Try escaping the double quotes

```
SELECT Name, ID INTO OUTFILE 'data.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM data
```

If this above query is working, then try escaping the backward slash again.

```
SELECT Name, ID INTO OUTFILE 'data.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM data
```